# change (denominations) calculator

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for a solution to calculate denominations of change.
My problem has the denominations: 50 & 20.

So given the amount: 130, there should be 1x50 + 4x20,
and amount: 80, there should be 0x50 + 4x20, etc.

I have tried looking up the coin problem but cannot get a decent answer, and when there are more than 2 types on denominations, there seems to be a brick wall for the coin problem (from what I've read).

Is there any complete solution to this? Or preferably a solution to more than 2 denomination types?

I would also like to be able to supply an amount of each available denomination.

Bonus if you can solve in pseedo code

Comment: found a solution here: http://condor.depaul.edu/~rjohnson/algorithm/coins.pdf

Comment: hate answering my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a code solution: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/coinChangeProblem.aspx

unfortunately the code is really ugly but should be able to clean up easily

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two denominations the problem becomes:

```
find x and y such that 
a*x + b*y = c
```

This can be solved using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

---

If you have more than 3 denominations, the most common solution uses uses dynamic programming to "brute force" the possibilities. You can check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518330/coin-change-problem-with-infinite-number-of-coins-of-each-denomination)

Comment: except that you are looking for nonnegative solutions, which compilcates matters a lot: there is a linear parametrization of the solution set with integers, and then you do eg. linear programming. For more than 3 variables, you can use the decomposition in elementary divisors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form ) of the left hand side 1xn matrix, which is computable in polynomial time. You still have to restrict to non negative solutions.

Comment: i'd be happy with a solution for just 2 denominations.

Comment: can you explain the solution for 2 denominations?

Answer (score 0):

Check the relative but more general question [looking-to-understand-the-rationale-for-money-denomination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/looking-to-understand-the-rationale-for-money-denomination) at math.stackexchange.com.

Also [making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems/15548#15548), which nicely explains how generating functions are the solution to the general problem.

If your problem is restricted to two coins, it's far more easier.

Answer (score 0):

u can use simple "greedy algorithm"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm

Answer (score -3):

Just keep subtracting the biggest denomination you can. IE keep subtracting 50s until whats left is <50, then keep subtracting 20s. This works no matter how many denominations you have.

Comment: The greedy approach doesn't work: If you want to get a total of 80 cents, using 50 and 20 cent coins, the only solution is 4x20 but the greedy solution gets stuck after 50 + 20

Comment: that would fail on 130. it would remove 2x50 then be left with something unusable for the 20s.

Comment: Yep its just a rubbish algorithm, I didn't think to just solve a*x + b*y = c

Comment: 130 fails no matter if you start with 50 or 20 !