# Calculate change received using php

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate change received, after payments, down to quarter, dimes, nickle, etc.

I feel like I am kinda lost in how I should be doing it.

```
if ($_GET['calc'] == "yes") {
    // Bills
    $fifty = 50;
    $twenty = 20;
    $ten = 10;
    $five = 5;
    $one = 1;
    // Coins
    $quater = .24;
    $dime = .10;
    $nickel = .05;
    $penny = .01;

    $cost = $_GET['cost'];
    $paid = $_GET['paid'];

    $change = 

}
```

If anyone is wondering, NO this is NOT a homework assignment, I am actually trying to learn php by myself. Here is my github challenge page: https://github.com/pavs/Programming-Challenge

---

Update: So I got it done. By doing reasonable modification of this example:
http://www.easyphpscripts.com/index.php?cat_select=Arrays&show=Change_Calculator

Let me know what you think. While individual answers were helpful, since I didn't use any of the code samples to finish my program I don't know if I should choose any correct result. I don't what's the right etiquette of stackoverflow in this case.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Change Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>For best results, try to have to have a change less than $200</p>

<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "GET">
    Cost: <input type = "text" name = "cost" size=4> <br />
    Paid: <input type = "text" name = "paid" size=4> <br />
<input type="hidden" name = "change" value = "yes">
<input type="submit" name = "Calculate"/>

</form>

<br>
<?php
/* Challenge 7: Change Return Program - The user enters a cost and then the amount of money given. 
The program will figure out the change and the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies needed for the change.

Modified http://www.easyphpscripts.com/index.php?cat_select=Arrays&show=Change_Calculator to get the result I wanted.
Satisfied with the result.
*/

function sanitizeString($var) 
{
    $var = stripslashes($var); 
    $var = htmlentities($var); 
    $var = strip_tags($var); 
    return $var;
} 

function have_need($have,$coin_value,$max){ 
    //Dave Husk, easyphpscripts.com 
    if($have < $coin_value) return(0); 
    while(1){ 
        if($have >= ($max * $coin_value)) return($max); 
        $max--; 
    } 
} 
function have_want($have,$coin_value,$max){ 
    //Dave Husk, easyphpscripts.com 
    if($have < $coin_value) return($have); 
    while(1){ 
        if($have >= ($max * $coin_value)) return($have - ($max * $coin_value)); 
        $max--; 
    } 
} 


$_GET['change']= sanitizeString($_GET['change']);


if ($_GET['change'] == "yes") {

    $cost = $_GET['cost'];
    $paid = $_GET['paid'];

    $change = $cost-$paid;

    $money = explode(".", round($change, 2));
    echo "Your total change is $$money[0] and $money[1] cents.</br>";

    }

$have =  $money[0]; 
$have0 = have_want($have,100,1); 
$have1 = have_want($have0,50,2); 
$have2 = have_want($have1,20,5); 
$have3 = have_want($have2,10,10); 
$have4 = have_want($have3,5,20); 


print("<table border=\"2\">"); 
print("<tr><th align=\"center\"><strong>100 Dollars</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>50 Dollars</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>20 Dollars</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>10 Dollars</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>5 Dollars</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>1 Dollar</strong></th></tr>"); 


print ('<tr><td align="right">'.have_need($have,100,1).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have0,50,2).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have1,20,5).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have2,10,10).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have3,5,20).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have4,1,100).'</td></tr>'); 



$have =  $money[1]; 
$have0 = have_want($have,100,1); 
$have1 = have_want($have0,50,2); 
$have2 = have_want($have1,25,4); 
$have3 = have_want($have2,10,10); 
$have4 = have_want($have3,5,20); 

print("<table border=\"2\">"); 
print("<tr><th align=\"center\"><strong>Dollars</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>Half Dollar Coins</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>Quarters</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>Dimes</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>Nickels</strong></th>"); 
print("<th align=\"center\"><strong>Pennies</strong></th></tr>"); 



print ('<tr><td align="right">'.have_need($have,100,1).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have0,50,2).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have1,25,4).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have2,10,10).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have3,5,20).'</td>'); 
print ('<td align="right">'.have_need($have4,1,100).'</td></tr>');



?>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by substracting cost from paid to get the change. So: `$change=$cost-$paid`. (Note: build in something to verify that change isn't negative). Then break down `$change` in smaller pieces. Start with the biggest bills (50,20,10,5,1) and then divide what is left in coins.

Comment: Sorry: `$change=$paid-$cost`.

Comment: no I think the original was right.

Comment: in the second answer, if `$change` is negative, the customer hasn't paid enough.

Comment: Oh shoot, you are right. Brain fart, how did I miss it?

Comment: Otherwise, it does the job, so your code is ok!

Comment: Related: [To calculate the optimal way to get to a value given a denomination set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18513637/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `$cost` is going to be the total value of the products bought, and `$paid` is the amount of money received. The change is clearly `$paid - $cost`.

Now in order to express the change in different notes and coins, the solution is rather more of a math problem than a PHP problem.

Given a change `$change`, simply begin by calculating how many notes of $50 fit into that value, by doing this:

```
$fifties = (int) ($change / $fifty);
```

The `(int)` is important, since it allows you to ignore the remainder; you're interested in the quotient only.

Now subtract the quotient from `$change`:

```
$change = $change - $fifty * $fifties;
```

You can now repeat this process for twenties, tens, fives, ones, all the way down to pennies. Of course, below the level of ones, you'll find that the values you're interested in are actually after the decimal point. One way to deal with this is by multiplying everything by 100, before doing the rest of the calculations.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know how hard it can be to study a programming language on your own (it involves an awful lot of Google) so I provide you with a solution to study, in case you can't solve it yourself.

```
// calculate the change
$change=$paid-$cost;
 echo "CHANGE: $change<br>";
// here something to check if there's enough paid

//set the value of all bills and coins in an array
$value=array(5000,2000,1000,500,100,24,10,5,1); //why the *100?

//fill the array $your_change with the amount of bills and coins the customer receives. 
$your_change=array();
foreach($value as $el){
    $your_change[$el]=0;
    }

// copy the value of $change to $left_over
$left_over=$change*100;

// loop trough all the parts, substracting the value from $left_over each time, 
// till it is 0
reset($value); //set the array-pointer to the first element
do{
    //get the current value
    $current_value = current($value);
    //test if left_over is bigger than the current bill/coin-value
    if($current_value>$left_over){
       //if true: go to bill/coin in the value-array
       next($value);
       }
    else{
       //substract the amount from left_over
       $left_over=(int)($left_over-$current_value);
       //add another bill/coin to the your_change array
       $your_change[$current_value]++;
       }
 }while($left_over>0);

$test=0;
foreach($your_change as $key=>$amount){
    echo ($key/100).": $amount times<br>";
    $test+=($key/100)*$amount;
    }
 echo "TOTAL: $test";
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, I really appreciate it. I gave it a shot on a different way (with some help), let me know what you think. Yours is obviously much professional, but I wanted to give it a shot myself.

Comment: That's the right way to do it. First try yourself, then look at what others do. Just gave you a (not _the_) solution to let you know what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to learn how to program in PHP then pick a simpler problem to solve.

Really. This is hard.

Your problem seems to be in deriving an algorithm not writing the code to implement it. (If you simlpy needed to solve the problem, then ISR there is learning example in a prolog tutorial somewhere on the internet).

If you simply want to calculate how to composite the change from an infinite supply of each denomination (a very abstract scenario) then it's relatively simple. But if you only have a finite amount of change and/or you want to minimise the number of coins/notes then the problem becomes exponentially more difficult.

Alex van Oostenrijk's solution addresses the simplest possible case but it's a particularly [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) - although this kind of task is usually set as a learning exercise for you to familarize yourself with the modulo operator ($change = $change % $fifty;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Changemaker</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Changemaker</h2>

<form name="buyit" action="./" method="post">
    <p>Cost: <input type="text" name="cost">
    <p>Cash Tendered:<input type="text" name="tendered"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="make change"></p>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $money = [100,50,20,10,5,2,1,0.50,0.20,0.10,0.05,0.02,0.01];

    //go get the posted values
    $cost = $_POST['cost'];
    $tendered = $_POST['tendered'];
    printf('You purchase something costing $%1.2f and tendered $%2.2f',$cost,$tendered);

    //work out change
    $change = $tendered - $cost;
    printf('<p>That makes $%1.2f change</p>',$change);
    echo '<p>made up of : ';
    if ($change >= 0){
        //enough money - work out breakdown
        for ($i=0;$i<count($money);$i++){
            while ($change >= $money[$i]){
                echo $money[$i].' ';
                //$change -=$money[$i]; is wrong because of binary
                $change = bcsub($change,$money[$i],2);

            }
        }

    } else {
        //insufficient funds
        echo '<p>Insufficient funds tendered</p>';
    }

} else {
    echo '<p>Enter an amount then press the button</p>';
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```