# Give change using optimal denominations *considering that using descending units might not result in a correct result

Tags: php, algorithm, math, currency, coin-change

I'm struggling to solve a problem regarding a programming challenge:

- **Rules:**
  The cash register only has $2, $5, and $10 bills. Your algorithm should determine the best way to give change for any amount, using the fewest bills possible.
- **Tests:**
  Your solution should include tests (unit or otherwise) covering the scenarios provided in the examples, as well as for the specific amounts of $10, $11, $21, $23, and $31.

  A few test inputs and the expected optimized results in plain English:

  ```
  $10: one $10 bill
  $11: one $5, three $2 bills 
  $21: one $10, one $5, three $2 bills
  $23: one $10, one $5, four $2 bills
  $31: two $10, one $5, three $2 bills
  ```

My coding attempt has a few flaws such as non-positive quantities of bills, inelegant handling of unsatisfiable amounts, and incorrect results for amounts like $23 and $31: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CiZb7))

```
function rendreMonnaie(int $montant)
{
    //Déclaration des variables
    $listeBillets = [10, 5, 2];  //Liste des coupure dispo
    $nbEntree = 0; //Combien de fois un chiffre entre dans le montant
    $message = [];
    $reste = 0;
    $result = 0;


    for ($ibillet = 0; $ibillet < sizeof($listeBillets); $ibillet++) {
        // Calcul du reste de la division du montant par le billet
        $reste = $montant % $listeBillets[$ibillet];
        if ($reste == 0) {
            // Si le reste est 0, le montant est un multiple du billet
            // Calcul du nombre de billets nécessaires
            $nbEntree = intdiv($montant, $listeBillets[$ibillet]);
            // Ajout du nombre de billets et du type de billet au message
            array_push($message, "$nbEntree x $listeBillets[$ibillet]");
            break;
        } else if ($reste >= $listeBillets[2]) {
            // Si le reste est supérieur ou égal au plus petit billet
            // Calcul du nombre de billets nécessaires
            $nbEntree = intdiv($montant, $listeBillets[$ibillet]);
            // Ajout du nombre de billets et du type de billet au message
            array_push($message, "$nbEntree x $listeBillets[$ibillet]");
            // Mise à jour du montant avec le reste
            $montant = $reste;
        } else {
            if ($listeBillets[$ibillet] == 2) { 
               $nbEntree = intdiv($result, $listeBillets[$ibillet]);
               array_push($message, "$nbEntree x $listeBillets[$ibillet]");
            } else {
                $result = $montant - $listeBillets[$ibillet];
                $reste = $reste % $listeBillets[$ibillet];
                // Calcul du nombre de billets nécessaires
                $nbEntree = intdiv($result, $listeBillets[$ibillet]);
                array_push($message, "$nbEntree x $listeBillets[$ibillet]");
            }
        }
    }
    // Affichage du tableau message pour le débogag
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($message); $i++) {
        // Suppression des éléments du message qui commencent par un nombre inférieur à 1
        if ($message[$i][0] < 1) {
            unset($message[$i]);
        }
    }
    // Conversion du tableau message en une chaîne de caractères
    $message = implode(" + ", $message);
    echo ($message);
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but some things you could improve: 1. Separate determining which bills to give, from outputting which bill you will give. This makes for clear and easier to read code. 2. All your code is in one function, something that's often called [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). Again this makes your code harder to read and debug. 3. Your code is a combination of French and English. This is fine when you're the only one having to read this, but this question shows that's not always the case. At least be consistent about it. English is preferred.

Comment: Have you analyzed the problem here? What is the algorithm you're implementing? Write this out in normal language first, then try the algorithm with the test amounts. Does it work? Only then start to implement it. Most beginning programmers start to write code before they've decided which algorithm to use, and then get stuck.

Comment: Related: [Calculate change received using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20989733/2943403)

Comment: @mickmackusa Not exactly a duplicate of the linked one since we don't have `1` in our denominations which makes this a little trickier. But sure, this is still a coin change problem.

Comment: @mickmackusa I beg to differ since it gives a wrong answers when `1` gets excluded. See https://3v4l.org/f5Ytd It gives wrong results for `23`. Could you please re-open?

Comment: @mickmackusa You do have a fair point but apparently my egg won't get me any value there because barely people skip past accepted answers to check the other ones.

Comment: @nice I think you are right about this question being significantly different from [the dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18513637/2943403).  I've unhammered.  Not because "people barely skip past accepted answers", but because the caveat in this challenge is a large enough degree of separation (IMO).

Comment: p.s. @nice, posting answers on Stack Overflow isn't supposed to "get **you** any value", the reason that you post answers is to "get **others** to a place that they otherwise wouldn't have reached as quickly (or at all)".  We are not meant to volunteer here for ourselves; volunteering should be done for the benefit of others.  If we gain something ourselves as a biproduct, then it is a bonus.  This is not a common lens for users to see this community through.

Comment: @mickmackusa Agreed, had the same intentions when I started, but slowly started to realise that many users took good stuff for granted and never acknowledged back with whether my answers actually solved their issues or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic [`coin change problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

---

Unfortunately, just applying a greedy approach(like you did) won't work since `1` ain't present in your denominations.

---

- To apply coin change algorithm here, we create an array called `$amtPossible`.
- This array will hold all the possible amounts we could make till `$totalAmount`(the total amount to be made).
- Every location of this array will hold `2` values. One is the minimum number of steps to get to this point and the other to tell us what was the last denomination that got us here.
- This will help us trace back what coins were actually involved in getting us the total amount (`$totalAmount`).
- The below code has `$amtPossible[ $i ][0] > 1 + $amtPossible[ $i - $d ][0]`. This simply means if the current denomination `$d` gives us less number of steps for a particular amount `$i` than what already exists for it, then update the `$i` with this new denomination. Rest is self-explanatory.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getCoins(int $totalAmount, $denominations = [2 ,5, 10]){
    $amtPossible = [];
    foreach($denominations as $d){
        $amtPossible[ $d ]= [1, $d];
        for($i = $d + 1; $i <= $totalAmount; ++$i){
            if(isset($amtPossible[ $i - $d ])){
                if(!isset($amtPossible[ $i ]) || $amtPossible[ $i ][0] > 1 + $amtPossible[ $i - $d ][0]){
                    $amtPossible[ $i ][0] = 1 + $amtPossible[ $i - $d ][0];
                    $amtPossible[ $i ][1] = $d;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(!isset($amtPossible[ $totalAmount ])){
        throw new \Exception("$totalAmount is not possible with the denominations ". implode(",", $denominations));
    }
    
    $coins = [];
    while($totalAmount > 0){
        $coins[] = $amtPossible[ $totalAmount ][1];
        $totalAmount -= $amtPossible[ $totalAmount ][1];
    }
    
    return $coins;
}

print_r(getCoins(23));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/L7ft1)

Comment: I really would have rathered English naming conventions. Ans is years if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @mickmackusa Changed the naming conventions. `ans` is actually stood for coins. I changed that as well.

Comment: I'm sorry sor the english and french, i'm belgian so mostly talking in french, thank for your kindness and help, now i see what was my problem, i gonna apply this sollution and try to have a better visual, thank you :)

Comment: Looks like a trustworthy answer/implementation: https://3v4l.org/pRQtm  I've taken some code-styling liberties and added some comments to help (myself) to understand the algorithm.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, I checked and the comments are correct.

Comment: @JérômeDelodder Fair enough. Can you please accept with a tick, the most readable and optimal answer so that researchers know that there are working solutions here..?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution, but it's by no means optimal (especially when the target amount becomes rather large). First let's define a class that contains a collection of multiple denominations that might contain a solution to the problem.

```php
class ChangeCollection
{
    public function __construct(protected array $denominations = [])
    {
    }

    public function getTotal()
    {
        return array_sum($this->denominations);
    }

    public function getDenominationsString()
    {
        sort($this->denominations);
        return implode(' ', $this->denominations);
    }

    public function addDenominations(array $denominations): array
    {
        return array_map(
            fn (int $denomination) => new ChangeCollection([...$this->denominations, $denomination]),
            $denominations
        );
    }
}
```

Now, we define a class that actually builds combinations of `ChangeCollection` objects and checks if it contains the actual solution.

```php
class ChangeCalculator
{
    protected const DENOMINATIONS = [2, 5, 10];

    public function calculate(int $target): ChangeCollection
    {
        $collections = [new ChangeCollection];
        do {
            $collections = array_filter(array_merge(...array_map(
                fn (ChangeCollection $collection) => $collection->addDenominations(self::DENOMINATIONS),
                $collections
            )), fn (ChangeCollection $collection) => $collection->getTotal() <= $target);

            foreach ($collections as $collection) {
                if ($collection->getTotal() === $target) {
                    return $collection;
                }
            }
        } while (count($collections) > 0);

        throw new Exception("There is no possible combination of denominations.");
    }
}
```

You can now get the string with the outcome with following code:

```php
$calculator = new ChangeCalculator;
echo $calculator->calculate(23)->getDenominationsString();
```

Comment: Looks like a trustworthy answer/implementation: https://3v4l.org/Ld58Q

Answer (score 1):

I am attracted to the elegance of a recursive approach for this task because by iterating the denominations in a descending order, you don't need to keep track of the most efficient path -- just halt the recursion upon encountering the first qualifying set.

Code with a range of tests: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tgFEi))

```
function optimalChange(int $amount, array $denominations): ?array {
    if (!$amount) {
        return []; // happy ending
    }

    foreach ($denominations as $d) {
        if ($d <= $amount) {
            $deeper = optimalChange($amount - $d, $denominations);
            if ($deeper !== null) {
                $result = array_merge([$d], $deeper);
                break; // run up the recursive branch
            }
        }
    }
    return $result ?? null;
}

$denominations = [10, 5, 2]; // must be rsort()ed at declaration
foreach (range(0, 35) as $target) {
    printf(
        "%s: %s\n",
        $target,
        json_encode(
            optimalChange($target, $denominations)
            ?: 'Sorry'
        )
    );
}
```

Output:

```
0: "Sorry"
1: "Sorry"
2: [2]
3: "Sorry"
4: [2,2]
5: [5]
6: [2,2,2]
7: [5,2]
8: [2,2,2,2]
9: [5,2,2]
10: [10]
11: [5,2,2,2]
12: [10,2]
13: [5,2,2,2,2]
14: [10,2,2]
15: [10,5]
16: [10,2,2,2]
17: [10,5,2]
18: [10,2,2,2,2]
19: [10,5,2,2]
20: [10,10]
21: [10,5,2,2,2]
22: [10,10,2]
23: [10,5,2,2,2,2]
24: [10,10,2,2]
25: [10,10,5]
26: [10,10,2,2,2]
27: [10,10,5,2]
28: [10,10,2,2,2,2]
29: [10,10,5,2,2]
30: [10,10,10]
31: [10,10,5,2,2,2]
32: [10,10,10,2]
33: [10,10,5,2,2,2,2]
34: [10,10,10,2,2]
35: [10,10,10,5]
```

Comment: I agree with the elegance of the recursive approach, and I must say you did a much nicer job than I cobbled together. Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

I kept my solution quite simple. First I started with creating two function that can add and remove bills from a simple array, and one function to sum the bills in that array:

```php
function addBills(&$change, $value, $count)
{
    $change = array_merge($change, array_fill(0, $count, $value));
}

function removeBill(&$change, $value)
{
    $key = array_search($value, $change);
    if ($key !== false) {
        unset($change[$key]);
    }
}

function getChangeTotal($change)
{
    return array_sum($change);
}
```

These helper functions come in handy to keep track of what I'm doing in the function that computes the minimal number of bills to return:

```php
function findMinimum($bills, $wantedTotal, $change = [])
{
    // without bills there's nothing to do
    if (count($bills) == 0) {
        return $change;
    }    
    // get the next smaller bill 
    $value = array_pop($bills);
    // how many of those will fit?
    $count = intdiv($wantedTotal - getChangeTotal($change), $value);
    if ($count > 0) {
        // add as many bills as will fit
        addBills($change, $value, $count);
        while ($count > 0) { 
            // can we find more change?
            $change = findMinimum($bills, $wantedTotal, $change);
            // did we reach the wanted total?
            if ($wantedTotal == getChangeTotal($change)) {
                return $change;
            } else {    
                // we have to use smaller bills
                $count--;
                removeBill($change, $value);
            }    
        }                                  
    }
    // try a smaller bill
    return findMinimum($bills, $wantedTotal, $change);
}

$bills = [2, 5, 10];

print_r(findMinimum($bills, 23));
```

This is a recursive function. The comments try to explain what it does. The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 2
)
```

I did not create a nice output message, but this shouldn't be hard to do.

For a live demo see: https://3v4l.org/TCRIA

Comment: Looks like a trustworthy answer/implementation: https://3v4l.org/Mg0td